# Our app is blocked from connecting to Google Fit. Waiting for verification email

Tags: google-fit

Google Fit sent us an email asking us to:

- Updated our Android app to build using Fitness SDK v20.0.0 or above
- Wait to apply for verification until you’re contacted by the Google Trust and Safety team.

We never received an email and **since our app is blocked from connecting to Google Fit**.

What is the right Google contact information to open a new case?

Comment: See https://developers.google.com/fit/improvements#when_to_apply_for_verification. "As of 27 April 2021 Google has not yet started sending verification invitations. So you have not missed any deadlines." Are you sure that there is not some other reason for being blocked?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest looking at https://developers.google.com/fit/support.

If you scroll down you can see two buttons, one for viewing question already asked and one for making new questions.

Comment: Thanks for sending the link.
I did use the 'new question' option to post this question.